# Moderator stats page doesn't highlight correctly with new beta theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

With the new beta theme, these are supposedly the highlighting key for stats on /admin:

> [image: highlighting stats guide]

This doesn't match what I see on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/admin:

> [image: actual stats highlighting]

Comment: Alright, now who's the slacker mod on SR? :P

Comment: Repro on [worldbuilding.se] as well, though with slightly different numbers (thankfully).

Comment: And another repro on [opensource.se]. Again, nicer numbers, same colours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch! We found the bug and squashed it. This will be fixed in our next production server build. Thanks.

Comment: [tag:status-completed]?? :)

Comment: Just waiting for a production build :) There's a few other things being worked on that aren't quite ready to go out yet.

Answer (score 0):

These disappeared on Cooking too, when it was switched to the new design.

My preference would be to not reimplement the highlighting, but just remove the color legend and leave all numbers black.